# Missing PyQt4 dialogs caption on ARM

Tags: arm, pyqt4

I am writing GUI code using PyQt4, as a cross platform library.

On both Windows and x86 Linux everything works fine, but when running on ARM, I'm getting strange behavior.  The one I'm trying to tackle now is the fact that dialogs on this platform appear without a caption, which is a little irritating.  This is true for both custom and standard dialogs.

Does any one have experience with how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I noticed that this effect also occurs in non PyQt windows, I looked and eventually traced the problem to the window manager (in this case fvwm)

The solution was to add the following line to the configuration:

`Style * DecorateTransient`